# How Android Open Gallery With Our own Image URLs?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I have downloaded the Android 3D Gallery Source from Github. I If i have run that code in Eclipse Its opening the images which are all already Available in the mobile.

I Just want to use that gallery source in my sample app and also want that .. if i click click gallery button means it should open the images which i am giving (URLs ) or (Images from internal memory ).

So please help me . i have go-ogled lot and  tried some ways but couldn't found the right one .
All the ideas and hints are always welcome. Thanks in advance.

Github URL : https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery3D